# MongoDB 3.2 C# driver version 2.2.3.3 Gridfs Download large files more than 2gb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I am uploading files using the following code:

```
using (var s = File.OpenRead(@"C:\2gbDataTest.zip"))           

{

 var t = Task.Run<ObjectId>(() =>

{

return fs.UploadFromStreamAsync("2gbDataTest.zip", s);

});


 return t.Result;

}

//works for the files below 2gb

  var t1 = fs.DownloadAsBytesAsync(id);

            Task.WaitAll(t1);
            var bytes = t1.Result;
```

I am getting error

[image]

I am new to MongoDb and C#, can any one please show me how to download files greater than 2GB in size?

Answer (score 2):

You are hitting the limit in terms of the size a byte array (kept in memory) download can be, so your only choice is to use a Stream instead like you are doing when you upload, something like (with a valid destination):

```
IGridFSBucket fs;
ObjectId id;
FileStream destination;

await fs.DownloadToStreamAsync(id, destination);
```

Comment: Hi Adam, Thank you for quick response. I tried using like below but i am getting Error {"Stream was too long."} :           MemoryStream destination = new MemoryStream();
            var t1 = fs.DownloadToStreamAsync(id, destination);
            Task.WaitAll(t1);

Comment: I think you may need a file stream rather than a memory stream - 2GB seems to be too large to fit in-memory, you are going to have to write it out to disk

Comment: Thanks alot for Answer.

Answer (score 0):

//Just writing complete code for others, This will work ; 
//**Thanks to "Adam Comerford"**

var fs = new GridFSBucket(database);

using (var newFs = new FileStream(filePathToDownload, FileMode.Create))

{

//id is file objectId

var t1 = fs.DownloadToStreamAsync(id, newFs);

Task.WaitAll(t1);

newFs.Flush();

newFs.Close();

}